# Почему люди, которые не имеет отношения к тем или иным метка, участвуют в закрытии вопросов?

Tags: поддержка

Этот вопрос нужно будет перенести или скорее всего он будет закрыт в связи с несоответствиям правил форума. 
Но если он дойдет к модераторам, следующий вопрос:

Почему люди, которые не имеет отношения к тем или иным метка(к примеру C++), участвуют в закрытии вопросов по темам в которых они не компетентны? 
Как данный [участник](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/262779/l-f-c) форума, не имея ни одного бала в метке `C++`, участвуя только в обсуждении проблем `HTML`, может голосовать о закрытии технического вопроса по `C++`, если он даже не понимает о чем там идет речь?

Если модераторы не имеют ответа, а у данного форума есть feedback сервис, можно ли получить ссылку на него и описать данную ситуацию службе поддержки.

Comment: Честно говоря, трудно ожидать чего то другого от подобной системы. В ней всегда толпа невежд и посредственностей задавит тех, кто выше нее. Хотя существует все именно за счет них. Отсюда вывод - грамотным специалистам совершенно не выгодно участвовать в подобных проектах - за их счет проект существует, но о специалиста в итоге все равно вытирают ноги, заставляя терпеть пинки от посредственностей и даже от неодушевленных программ-ботов. Всякие плюсики и подъем репутации - развод как в казино. Отвечать здесь - невыгодно.

Comment: То есть специалистам следует искать или создавать другие ресурсы, существующие хотя бы в традиционной форме форумов, которыми владеют программисты - грамотные специалисты в определенной области и где нет никаких рейтингов и ботов.

Comment: Вы забыли дать ссылку на вопрос.

Comment: feedback можно дать в разделе «[Связаться с нами](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/contact)». Также можете попробовать поговорить с модераторами в [чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/?tab=site&host=ru.stackoverflow.com)). Если не согласны с закрытием вопроса, то прочитайте раздел справки «[Что делать, если я не согласен с закрытием вопроса? Как его открыть снова?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/reopen-questions)» там подробно расписано что нужно делать в таких случаях.

Comment: Пока Ваш вопрос даже для меты несколько общий. Здесь много всего: (1) несправедливое закрытие вопроса; (2) предложение по изменению механики сайта; (3) и вопрос по связи с модераторами. Если хотите из текущего вопроса извлечь какую-либо пользу рекомендую сконцентрироваться на чем-то одном.

Comment: По сути вопроса: за закрытие голосуют пять человек. Вы выбрали из них одного, перешли на личности и безосновательно обвинили человека в некомпетентности. Так делать имхо не стоит, даже если человек действительно ошибся. Если Вы вместо этого дадите ссылку на вопрос и приведете доводы для его открытия, то Вам помогут быстрее. P.S. Извиняюсь за много букав в комментах, на ответ это не тянет по-моему.

Comment: @defaultlocale Переоткрыл вопрос. Пожалуйста, опубликуйте ваши комментарии в виде ответа (на мой взгляд, может получится очень хороший ответ).

Comment: @defaultlocale соглашусь с вами на счет обобщенности вопроса, но к сожалению, данный участник (а его лично я никак не хочу, ни в чем обидеть, а только констатирую факты) не однократно участвовал в похожих ситуациях закрывая или расставляя флаги по всему форуму и как я понимаю, это делалось с целью набить фейковый рейтинг. 
К примеру, я или другой человек, который ищет ответы на свои вопросы не хожу по темам о которых я представления не имею, чтобы там поставить какие-то плюсики, минусики, потому что "там" я никому и ничем помочь не смогу.

Comment: А крайний вопрос по C++ таки открыли)

Comment: Вообще, мне кажется, механизмами сайта подразумевается, что любой может закрыть вопрос за очевидные проблемы: отсутствие примера кода, просьба выполнить домашку, неадекватный русский язык, сфотографированный на тапок экран и так далее. А некомпетентное закрытие это уже отдельные «перегибы на местах». Однако если запрещать влезать в «не свою» тему, то тогда откровенно плохие вопросы по экзотическим темам будут оставаться открытыми, что тоже плохо для сайта

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky Спасибо за предложение, опубликовал ответ, хотя сам до сих пор считаю что вопрос слишком общий. Думаю было бы неплохо и Вам дать ответ хотя бы по форме обратной связи, тем более что автор обращается непосредственно к модераторам

Comment: @PavelMayorov а какой был первый?

Comment: @raviga странно, я видел от вас два вопроса...

Comment: @raviga, так о каком конкретно вопросе по С++ идет речь?

Comment: @avp речь была конкретно об этом вопросе (http://bit.do/eQmGt). Вопрос открыли, но это не первый случай, когда вопросы закрывались по непонятным причинам без адекватного объяснения и от людей с других секций форума.

Comment: @raviga, да уж, вопрос как вопрос.  Наверное  сам язык так влияет ([C++ damages the brain … – EWD](http://harmful.cat-v.org/software/c++/))

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Ранее я проголосовал за закрытие, т.к. на мой взгляд Ваш вопрос даже для меты несколько общий. Здесь много всего:

1. несправедливое закрытие вопроса;
2. предложение по изменению механики сайта;
3. вопрос по связи с модераторами.

Если хотите из текущего вопроса извлечь как можно больше пользы, то рекомендую сконцентрироваться на чем-то одном.

Теперь @NicolasChabanovsky переоткрыл вопрос и попросил оформить мои комментарии в виде ответа, что я и делаю.

Я ни разу не модератор и все что ниже мое личное мнение. Если хотите разобрать эти вопросы подробнее можете попробовать задать более точный вопрос.

### Несправедливое закрытие вопроса

**TL;DR:** Обсуждайте отдельные вопросы, иначе ничего не понятно.

Если не согласны с закрытием вопроса, то прочитайте раздел справки «[Что делать, если я не согласен с закрытием вопроса? Как его открыть снова?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/reopen-questions)» там расписаны шаги, которые можно предпринять в таких случаях. Один из способов добиться переоткрытия это задать вопрос здесь на мета-сайте.

При переоткрытии вопроса я бы рекомендовал сосредоточиться на объективной стороне дела: рассказать про закрытый вопрос, указать причину закрытия и объяснить почему вопрос следует открыть заново. Так у других участников и у модераторов есть шанс понять что происходит и насколько обоснованы Ваши претензии.

Обсуждение самого вопроса принесет пользу как Вам так и сообществу:

- участники быстрее найдут вопрос и проголосуют за его открытие;
- если с вопросом действительно есть проблемы, то Вам могут подсказать что именно можно в нем исправить;
- если вопрос был закрыт по ошибке, то проголосовавшим за закрытие объяснят их ошибку и они извлекут из нее урок.

Вы же пошли по несколько другому пути:

> Как данный участник форума, не имея ни одного бала в метке C++, участвуя только в обсуждении проблем HTML, может голосовать о закрытии технического вопроса по C++, если он даже не понимает о чем там идет речь?

За закрытие голосуют пять человек. Вы выбрали из них одного, перешли на личности и безосновательно обвинили человека в некомпетентности. Так делать имхо не стоит, даже если человек действительно ошибся.

Сосредотачиваться на человеке не стоит хотя бы по двум причинам:

- то, что четверо других участников решили закрыть Ваш вопрос уже говорит о проблемах с которыми надо бы разобраться;
- при этом Вы переходите из объективной плоскости в субъективную. Ваш вопрос целиком находится здесь и мы можем его обсудить. Мы не можем объективно оценить знания (репутация  очень плохо для этого подходит) и, тем более, мотивацию того или иного человека.

> ... к сожалению, данный участник (а его лично я никак не хочу, ни в чем обидеть, а только констатирую факты) не однократно участвовал в похожих ситуациях закрывая или расставляя флаги по всему форуму и как я понимаю, это делалось с целью набить фейковый рейтинг.

Пока Вы дали нам только свой вывод, а самих фактов не привели. Предлагаю разбираться с вопросами по одному. Если выяснится что участник действительно систематически нарушает правила, то модераторы могут принять меры. Но это не единственный вариант развития событий: возможно, сообщество решит что вопросы были закрыты справедливо, а возможно, мнения на этот счет разделятся.

Повторюсь: участник не может закрывать вопросы в одиночку (за небольшими исключениями), то что человек не понял вопроса — домысел, то что он это делает ради некоего рейтинга — домысел, тем более что за закрытие вопросов репутации не дают.

### Предложение по изменению механики сайта

**TL;DR:** Идея небессмысленна, но жесткое ограничение представляется мне непрактичным.

Сейчас, любой человек, который набирает 3000 баллов репутации получает доступ к привилегии «[Закрывать и переоткрывать](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/close-questions)». После этого человек может голосовать за закрытие/переоткрытие любых вопросов.

Это имеет смысл т.к. репутация является меркой того насколько человек знаком с правилами сайта. Например, если кто-то задаст вопрос:

> Решите мне домашку, как вычислить фебаначи рекурсией и подробнее, я нафечёг

, то очевидно, что такой вопрос следует закрыть. И то, что автор вопроса проставит по нему метки [искусственный-интеллект](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%ba%d1%83%d1%81%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b2%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b9-%d0%b8%d0%bd%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%82) и [haskell](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/haskell) не значит, что закрывать его должны люди с глубоким опытом разработки AI систем на Haskell.

Еще один момент: по репутации ни в коем случае нельзя оценивать уровень технических знаний участников. Человек может отвечать на множество простых вопросов по C++, при этом обладая крайне поверхностными знаниями языка. И наоборот, человек может обладать достаточным опытом для оценки вопроса и при этом не принимать активное участие в вопросах по C++.

Предполагается что люди будут сами оценивать свои способности и голосовать за закрытие вопроса с осторожностью. Разумеется любой человек может допустить ошибку. Даже очень квалифицированный специалист может неверно истолковать вопрос, особенно если он расписан скудно. Как раз поэтому для закрытия вопроса требуется пять голосов, это уменьшает вероятность ошибки.

По этим причинам предложение ограничивать привилегии пользователей в метках, в которых они не участвуют мне видится непрактичным. Но при этом оно не кажется мне совсем уж абсурдным. Если идею продумать получше и сконцентрироваться на отдельных причинах закрытия то может получиться дельное предложение, но это уже тема для нового вопроса.

Также нужно иметь ввиду, что на сайте есть участники, которые тратят много времени и сил на модерацию вопросов. Они выполняют полезную и неблагодарную работу без которой сайт не сможет нормально функционировать: уточняют и правят вопросы, расставляют метки, закрывают дубликаты и проблемные вопросы, удаляют спам и т.д. Ограничения на закрытие вопросов могут помешать их работе, что нежелательно.

### Вопрос по связи с модераторами

Привлечь внимание модераторов можно разными способами (от простого к сложному):

- поднять тревогу на том или ином вопросе, указать, что требуется вмешательство модератора;
- написать пост на мете;
- перейти в [чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/?tab=site&host=ru.stackoverflow.com) и поговорить с [модераторами](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/site-moderators) (это сотрудник Stack Overflow [@NicolasChabanovsky](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/users/6/nicolas-chabanovsky) и [избранные модераторы](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users?tab=moderators)) там, возможно, в свободном формате общения быстрее выяснится в чем дело;
- написать в службу поддержки на странице «[Связаться с нами](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/contact)».

Какой бы способ Вы ни выбрали, приготовьтесь как можно подробнее описать факты нарушений, указать ссылки и привести свои доводы. Так Вы сэкономите время и себе и модераторам.

Comment: Примеры: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/970416/revisions , https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/962254/revisions Некорректное закрытие вопросов в метке С++ - обычная вещь, но виноват в этом, конечно, не L.F.C. Эти вопросы вообще не должны были попасть в очередь закрытия, если на то пошло.

Comment: @MSDN.WhiteKnight Я и не сомневался, что примеры есть, и не только в C++. Я о том, что в принципе полезнее разбирать вопросы в отдельности, чтобы закрывальщики могли объяснить что показалось не так и понять свою ошибку.

Comment: Ответ понятен. 
Возможно с моей стороны было грубостью указать ссылку именно этого участника, но в основном подразумевалось то, что таких пользователей SO действительно много и очень часто из-за токсичности и просто желании набить фейковый рейтинг, люди не дают возможности разобраться с проблемами, которые именно данный форум призван решать и помогать в их решении. 
Но по сути, с ответа понятно, что нужно делать в таких ситуациях, по этому отмечаю как правильный но надеюсь в будущем будет добавлена механика защиты от спамеров рейтингом. Так как в первую очередь, это нужно самому SO.

Comment: @raviga Рад, если помог. Называть человека спамером, да, пожалуй, грубо, тем более голословно. Про рейтинг не совсем понятно что Вы имеете ввиду, за закрытие вопроса его не начисляют. Если у Вас будут конкретные предложения по улучшению, предлагаю их опубликовать здесь на мете, мне будет интересно почитать. Только я бы предложил сначала самому дойти до 3К (Вам недолго осталось), чтобы познакомиться поближе с тем как работает закрытие.

Answer (score 6):

Если обсуждать не конкретные вопросы, а в общем - то все довольно просто. Вопросы открываются и закрываются в соответствии с правилами сайта. Предполагается, что опытный участник хорошо знает цели, правила и традиции сайта, что и даёт его голосу вес.

Надо понимать, что:

1. правила сайта устанавливают требования не только к содержанию вопроса, но и к его форме (вкратце, вопрос должен иметь форму вопроса) - и проверить форму способен любой участник, даже с нулевыми знаниями по теме;
2. закрывается вопрос пятью голосами, а не одним (одним голосом вопрос может закрыть только модератор - и они-то точно знают все правила сайта);
3. закрытие вопроса - довольно долгий процесс, и вы, как автор вопроса, можете успеть отредактировать его, устранив замечания, либо аргументированно оспорить закрытие в комментариях к вопросу (только, пожалуйста, не путайте аргументы и оскорбления);
4. даже если вы не успели и вопрос был закрыт - его всегда можно переоткрыть, причём запросы на переоткрытие, как правило, изучаются внимательнее запросов на закрытие.

Comment: и еще золотой знак может закрыть одним голосом как дубликат

Comment: @Grundy ну, дубликат - не вполне закрытие, хоть технически он считается закрытием. Это скорее ответ-ссылка.

Comment: Ну как минимум это не дает больше добавлять новые ответы

Comment: @Grundy можно добавлять ответы к целевому вопросу, в сторону которого произведено закрытие.

Comment: @Grundy `золотой знак может закрыть одним голосом как дубликат` —потому что золото как раз и свидетельствует о компетентности, которую упомянул вопрошающий.

Answer (score 5):

Вопрос слишком комплексный. Навскидку:

1. Закрывается вопрос голосами нескольких людей. Если 5 человек посчитали, что вопрос требует закрытия, то это о чём-то говорит.
2. Если закрыли ошибочно (бывает, да), то всегда можно переоткрыть. Можно в чате обсудить.
3. Чтобы закрывать вопросы, не нужно разбираться именно в этой технологии, если вопрос закрывается как "домашка" или "too broad". Там, в общем-то, и так всё понятно. Другое дело, если вопрос закрыт как дубликат. Привет, Грунди (¬‿¬)
4. У нас в очередях мало народу. Если закрывать будут только по своей области вопросы участники, то очередь никогда не разгребётся.

Comment: @Grundy закрывает только 100% дубликаты :)

Comment: @Grundy но это неточно (¬‿¬)

Comment: Точнее не бывает ;-)